# CSS/HTML Padding issue

Tags: php, html, css, padding

Here is what i try to do:

I load my tags from MYSQL, and i use css, to make them look nice. But when one tag field is empty, it still apear the border and the padding ... as an empty box, with no text inside. How to make, to not display that border and padding when the tag field is empry?

HTML code:

```
<a  href="#<?php echo $tag1;?>.php" class="tag" style="position: relative; top: 0px"><?php echo $tag1;?></a>
```

CSS code:

```
.tag {
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
background-color:#ededed;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
border-radius:5px;
border:1px solid #dcdcdc; 
display:inline-block;
color:#777777;
font-family:arial;
font-size:10px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;
text-align:left;
text-decoration:none;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
float:left;
margin:5px 0px 0px 5px;
}.tag:hover {
background-color:#dfdfdf;
}.tag:active {
position:relative;
top:1px;
}
```

Comment: Is there something I'm missing?  Why not just not render empty tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not only render valid tags?

```
<?php if(strlen($tag1) > 0) { ?>

<a  href="#<?php echo $tag1;?>.php" class="tag" style="position: relative; top: 0px"><?php echo $tag1;?></a>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, it`s working fine. I didn`t know about: <?php if(strlen($tag1) > 0) { ?>  Thank you again

Comment: You're welcome, remember, do as much as you can server side, it is easier!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to generate the complete anchor tag on server side (php) and return no response if the tag is empty.